# Pandas Dataframe groupby with overlapping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using a pandas dataframe to read a csv that has data points for machine learning. I'm trying to come up with a way that would allow me to index a dataframe where it would get that index and the next N number of rows. I don't want to group the data frame into bins with no overlap (i.e. index 0:4, 4:8, etc.) What I do want is to get a result like this: index 0:4, 1:5, 2:6,etc. How would this be done?

Comment: See rolling window functions.

Comment: @Kyle, That's exactly what I was looking for. How would I then be able to take those windows and make them indexable so I could get index x and the N number of rows after that?

Comment: Please consider adding more details for clarity. A minimal reproducible code will also be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a list of DataFrames, like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nrows = 7
group_size = 5

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.randint(0, 10, nrows)})
print(df)

grp = [df.iloc[x:x+5,] for x in range(df.shape[0] - group_size + 1)]
print(grp[1])
```

Original DataFrame:

```
   col1
0     2
1     6
2     6
3     5
4     3
5     3
6     8
```

2nd DataFrame from the list of DataFrames:

```
   col1
1     6
2     6
3     5
4     3
5     3
```